# Pushbots and Ionic App

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework, pushbots

I am trying to implement the pushbots code into my ionic app to have push notifications via - [Pushbots docs](https://pushbots.com/developer/docs/phonegap)

What I can't seem to figure out is where the following code goes:

```
if(PushbotsPlugin.isAndroid()){
    PushbotsPlugin.initializeAndroid("PUSHBOTS_APP_ID", "GCM_SENDER_ID");
}
```

does it go in the below code if so where abouts:

```
    .run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicAnalytics, $window) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {


  /*  $ionicAnalytics.register();*/
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }

    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

or would it go in the config?

Answer (score 0):

The initialization code for Pushbots should go into a function that is called when the 'deviceready' event is fired. In your case, given you have an Ionic project, the code should go into a *$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {})* code block.

You can use the existing block:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicAnalytics, $window) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(PushbotsPlugin.isAndroid()){
        PushbotsPlugin.initializeAndroid("PUSHBOTS_APP_ID", "GCM_SENDER_ID");
    }

    /*  $ionicAnalytics.register();*/
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }

    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Or you can create a separate block, to keep things clean and untangled:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicAnalytics, $window) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(PushbotsPlugin.isAndroid()){
        PushbotsPlugin.initializeAndroid("PUSHBOTS_APP_ID", "GCM_SENDER_ID");
    }
  });

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    /*  $ionicAnalytics.register();*/
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }

    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Hi Alin, i get a error in the console which is: Uncaught ReferenceError: PushbotsPlugin is not defined

Comment: You need to install the plugin (*cordova plugin add com.pushbots.push*) and add the script tag to your index.html: *<script src="path/to/pushbots.js"></script>*

Comment: Actually, scratch that: the script tag should not be necessary

Comment: With that script tag i get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined and without the tag i still get that error

Comment: Before the "module is not defined" error, isn't there any other error? Here's a blogpost of an example app with Pushbots: http://thejackalofjavascript.com/pushbots-and-cordova/ There's no mention of the script tag being required. And it shouldn't be required, Cordova should handle the loading of the plugin JS file on its own. When I mentioned the script tag, I was thinking about something else (bower components, not cordova plugins)

Comment: Hi @AlinPandichi I followed your link, I am able to register my device in pushbot's but unable to receive the notification to the device's and in pushbot's Dashboard it is showing as message delivered ... If you have any working example please post it

Comment: Here is the GitHub repo with the demo app done by the same guy: https://github.com/arvindr21/pushbots-cordova